# word for value which is added or subtracted to total value of a sales invoice to round it i?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider I'm going to a shop and want to buy some stuff which costs 1.97$.

Some shops round this value to 2.0$ for the sake of ease in payment by cash/coins.

What is this 3 cents(0.03$) is called in a sales invoice? Is there any specific words for it?

Comment: Many years ago I used to frequent a pub where the landlord habitually said ***X pounds for cash!*** if the bill for a round of drinks was just a few pence more ***or less*** than ***X*** pounds. From time to time I used to point out to him that whereas it was totally reasonable for ***him to offer me*** a few pence ***off*** the bill if it was just over a whole number of pounds, it should be up to ***me*** to say ***Keep the change!*** if the bill was actually ***less*** than the amount I handed over. He agreed with me in principle - just not in practice.

Comment: :D I think the amount you got as discount when bill was more than X pounds would had neutralized the amount you paid when number was less than X pound. However as your noticed it is up to you to decide if he could keep the change when the number was less than X pounds. I loved the `just not in practice` part :))

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is mark-up: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mark-up

Comment: When it is less it is a [**discount**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discount). It is called [**overcharging**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/overcharge) even when it's a few pence more. It gets me: shops price their goods just under an exact number of pounds, dollars or whatever to trick you into thinking its a whole pound cheaper, and then they resent it when you want the change.

Comment: @Weathervane In Chile, change is legally rounded to ten CLP since a few years ago, since when the smaller-denomination coins have been eliminated. In between there was a time period in which the small coins were still circulating, but at the bank and so on we were required to expect rounding to ten.

Comment: @Weather... cont It's got a name in Wikipedia since inflation is so prevalent world-wide: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_rounding

Comment: @Conrado roll on the cashless society, it's coming even sooner with the current problems.

Comment: @WeatherVane right- with plastic money the transaction can be right on the peso.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is round-off a good word for this?

Comment: @VSB - I would not call it round-off.  I’d call it round-up.

Comment: I think it's of no real consequence what ***I*** think, because we're not talking about a "standard" usage that you might hope to find in a dictionary. Different people working in different businesses might feasibly develop their own domain-specific terminology. But for what it's worth, the nearest definition in the full OED is **rounding** (n.3) subsense 8: *The **action or an act** of rounding a number. Frequently with **down, off,** or **up***. Which to me implies we might sensibly call the amount a ***rounding-off*** to include both the ***-up*** and ***-down*** adjustments.